# Debugging xml ElementTrees in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML string

```
xml_str = '<Foo><Bar>burp</Bar></Foo>'
```

I'm parsing it with xml etree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root_element = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
```

This creates an Element object(root_element) with a tag, tail, text, and attrib values within it. I can see all of them when debugging. However, I can't see any children Elements while debugging. I know the children are there because I can access them in a for loop.

```
for child in root_element:
    *break point here*
```

Below is a screenshot of what I'm seeing

[image: debugger]

Is there a way to see all elements at once while debugging? And is this issue because the XML parser is a JIT parser or something?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be able to see the available elements in the XML document you want to parse.

This will list **all** the child tags of the root element

```
all_children = list(root_element.iter())
```

This will produce

```
[<Element 'Foo' at 0x11b315908>, <Element 'Bar' at 0x11b315c28>]
```

This output, however, doesn't respect the 'shape' of the XML.

When I want to parse XML, I find it easier to use ElementTree but my first experiences parsing XML was with BeautifulSoup. I still like the prettify() function.

This code,

```
pretty = ""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_str, 'html.parser') 
for value in soup.find_all("foo"):
    pretty += value.prettify()
```

produces this output

```
print(pretty)

<foo>
 <bar>
  burp
 </bar>
</foo>
```

You can replace the find_all() with specific elements you might be looking for.

Comment: Using xml.minidom's parseString() solved my problem of not being able to see the entire XML while debugging, but it's still weird that ET doesn't show everything while debugging. I would like to know why I can easily debug minidom, but not ET.